# Raspberry Pi MicroSD Boot not working, MicroSD card unreadable on PC

Tags: raspberry-pi

I downloaded the necessary files for Raspberry Pi onto a MicroSD card, although the MicroSD card is no longer readable. When I put the card into the computer through a MicroSD to USB adapter nothing shows up in Windows Explorer. The card isn't present in Windows Disk Management either.

How do I fix the MicroSD card to get Raspberry Pi running properly?

Comment: How did you download the data onto the card?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I formatted the card with SD Formatter 4.0 and then put the files on through Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Pi won't boot off it (ie can't read it) and Windows can't read it I would assume the card has died, is it a good brand or a no name one? It may be worth just grabbing another one to test with.

Comment: I figured it might be an issue with a shoddy brand, the MicroSD is fine but the MicroSD to USB adapter was a no name brand. when I used a MicroSD to SD adapter and then formatted the MicroSD using a camera I got it working again